# Common styles for all screens in a React Native app

Tags: css, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm working on my first React Native (Expo) app, and I'm trying to set a common background color for all my screens:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Chat from "./screens/Chat";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Settings from "./screens/Settings";
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from "react-native";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNav() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name={"Home"} component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name={"Chat"} component={Chat} />
      <Tab.Screen name={"Settings"} component={Settings} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={TabNav} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

After lots of Googling and experimenting, I can't seem to find a way to set a common background color for all the screens I'm adding to `<NavigationContainer>`. This of course could go beyond just background color, like setting common flex settings for all screens. I thought wrapping `<NavigationContainer>` in a `<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}}>` would do the trick, but that didn't work either.

Surely there's a common pattern for adding a background color to all screens in a navigator, right? Or for all screens in an app in general? Am I missing something here?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

unfortnelly i didnt find a global style for all the screens in NativeStackNavigator, but it is possible atleast with StackNavigator and TabsNavigator:

in StackNavigator you might use cardStyle prop from screenOptions
here i have an example:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator(); // note: this is not createNativeStackNavigator

const StackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{cardStyle:{backgroundColor:'orange'}}}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Screen4" component={Screen4} />
            <Stack.Screen name="NotificationsScreen" component={NotificationsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

now in TabNavigator you might use sceneContainerStyle prop:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabParamList>();

const UserTab = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} options={options.Screen1}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} options={options.Screen2}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} options={options.Screen3}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen4" component={Screen4} options={options.Screen4}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="NotificationsScreen" component={NotificationsScreen} options={{tabBarButton:() => null}}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

if these solutions is not what you might want, i suggest you to create a wrapperComponent which will have the background you need and then put inside all of the screens.

Answer (score 0):

contentStyle from screenOptions of NativeStackNavigation apply to its screens the styles you want including backgroundColor.